# Get multiples database on the same server

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, sql-server-2014, adonis.js

I use AdonisJS and MSSQL. I have some databases on the same server : https://i.stack.imgur.com/pJKVE.png

In my .env I have this configuration :

```
DB_CONNECTION=mssql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=1433
DB_USER=sa
DB_PASSWORD=123456
DB_DATABASE=WEB_PANEL
```

The problem is, i have my own API to make requests like that :

```js
connectToDatabase('mssql://id:pw@localhost').then(async () => {
            let onlinePlayers = await User.getOnlinePlayers()
            let numberOfStaff = staff.length
            let numberOfOnlinePlayers = onlinePlayers.recordset.length

            return view.render('system.index', { totalPlayers: numberOfOnlinePlayers, numberOfStaff: numberOfStaff })
        })
    }
```

And I have this error :

```
warning:
warning:
  WARNING: Adonis has detected an unhandled promise rejection, which may
  cause undesired behavior in production.
  To stop this warning, use catch() on promises or wrap await
  calls inside try/catch.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'substr' of null
    at parseConnectionURI (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\mssql\lib\connectionstring.js:21:32)
    at Object.resolveConnectionString [as resolve] (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\mssql\lib\connectionstring.js:205:72)
    at new ConnectionPool (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:127:40)
    at new ConnectionPool (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\mssql\lib\tedious.js:175:1)
    at Object.connect (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\mssql\lib\base.js:1592:22)
    at connectToDatabase (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\drapi\src\core\connection.handler.js:4:15)
    at SystemController.showSystemPage (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\app\Controllers\Http\Panel\SystemController.js:8:9)
    at Server._routeHandler (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\@adonisjs\framework\src\Server\index.js:121:31)
    at MiddlewareBase._resolveMiddleware (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\@adonisjs\middleware-base\index.js:195:28)
    at Runnable._invoke (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\co-compose\src\Runnable.js:76:42)
    at C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\co-compose\src\Runnable.js:73:34
    at f (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\once\once.js:25:25)
    at Authenticated.handle (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\app\Middleware\Authenticated.js:16:19)
    at async ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.handle (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\app\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.js:13:5)
    at async AuthInit.handle (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\@adonisjs\auth\src\Middleware\AuthInit.js:60:5)
    at async Shield.handle (C:\Users\didi\Desktop\drpanel\panel\node_modules\@adonisjs\shield\src\Shield\index.js:417:5)
```

And for example getOnlinePlayers() is :

```js
    static async getOnlinePlayers() {
        let onlinePlayers = await sql.query`
        USE DR2_USER
        SELECT TOP 10 * FROM TB_CharacterSub
        WHERE f_ConnectionChannel != 0`

        return onlinePlayers
    }
```

For example I want to use the DR2_USER database but i can't :/

Please someone has a solution ?

Thanks !

Comment: I do not see how the first question that you ask, "how to connect to multiple databases," relates in any way to the actual problem that you describe concerning "promises."

Comment: Specifically with regard to "multiple databases," these settings are *convenient defaults,* which allow the language to automagically create (one ...) database connection for you.  But you can always create your own explicit "database connection" and issue your query calls using that connection.

Comment: I try to make my own db connection but I can't, i have the error :/

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your `config/database.js` to configure multiple database connections and set the Lucid Model to use that connection

https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/lucid#_connection

```
class User extends Model {
  static get connection () {
    return 'mysql'
  }
}
```